# How do I change column count of a GridLayout dynamically in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want to set the number of column of a GridLayout by the width of the window.

But, these sort of codes don't work in onCreate() function.

```
GridLayout gLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.a_grid_layout);
gLayout.setColumnCount(4);
```